# Split two numbers in two arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to split 2 numbers in the form(they are from a text file):

```
Num1:Num2
Num3:Num4
```

And store num1 into array X and number 2 in array Y num 3 in array X and num4 in array Y.

Comment: I do not know bash but here https://stackabuse.com/substrings-in-bash/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
mapfile -t X < <(cut -d : -f 1 file) # read only first column
mapfile -t Y < <(cut -d : -f 2 file) # read only second column
declare -p X Y
```

Output:

```
declare -a X='([0]="num1" [1]="num3")'
declare -a Y='([0]="num2" [1]="num4")'
```

Disadvantage: The file is read twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform the following steps:

- Create destination arrays empty
- Read file line by line, with a classic `while read ... < file` loop
- Split each line on `:`, again using `read`
- Append values to arrays

For example:

```
arr_x=()
arr_y=()
while IFS= read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    IFS=: read x y <<< "$line"
    arr_x+=("$x")
    arr_y+=("$y")
done < data.txt

echo "content of arr_x:"
for v in "${arr_x[@]}"; do
    echo "$v"
done

echo "content of arr_y:"
for v in "${arr_y[@]}"; do
    echo "$v"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick bash solution:

```
c=0
while IFS=: read a b ;do
 x[$c]="$a"
 y[$c]="$b"
 c=$((c+1))
done < input.txt
```

We send the input.txt to a while loop, using Input Field Separator : and read the first number of each line as $a and second number as $b. Then we add them to the array as you specified. We use a counter $c to iterate the location in the arrays.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you. I added an explanation of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using `=~` operator to store the pair of numbers to array `$BASH_REMATCH`:

```
$ cat file
123:456
789:012
$ while read -r line
do 
    [[ $line =~ ([^:]*):(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    # do something else with numbers as they will be replaced on the next iteration
done < file
```